# What is the source type for .CSV files in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS.

I have a sample .CSV file and i want to transfer the data from .CSV file to SQL DB.

So what is the DataSource type for .csv files.

I created the Package for excel and load the data to SQL server.

please advice me........

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need Flat File source, not Excel.

Comment: Thanks for update. And the Bulk Insert we can use if there is no operation with data in DataFlow

Answer (score 1):

Use a bulk insert which is describe in this forum post here:

[Bulk Insert to SQL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a3e3273c-2c90-4d7b-91de-00f0569ecfb6/)